# How do you pass the value of a variable to a firebase call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

Copied from firebase docs:

```
// Create an initial document to update.
var frankDocRef = db.collection("users").doc("frank");
frankDocRef.set({
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" },
    age: 12
});

// To update age and favorite color:
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "age": 13,
    "favorites.color": "Red"
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
});
```

I want to be able to do:

```
const var1 = 'color'
const color = 'red'
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "age": 13,
    "favorites.$var1$": color
})
```

where `$var1$` refers to the value that `$var1$` holds, in this case either food, color or subject.

Bracket notation does not work in this case, as I am passing a string to firebase, which it doesn't interpret like that.

Building the string beforehand like:

```
const aString = 'favorites.' + var1
```

also does not work, as you cannot pass the variable `aString` like this:

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "age": 13,
    aString: "Red"
})
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

Use square brackets `[]`:

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "age": 13,
    [aString]: "Red"
})
```

For more information, see [MDN - Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)